# Flask Shell to run multiple line command?

Tags: flask

### Context

OS to be Ubuntu Desktop

Python & Flask to be [installed in virtual environment](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/installation/)

Run [Flask-Alchemy quickstart](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/quickstart/) from Flask Shell i.e. `flask shell`

### My need

Run a command with multiple line, is it possile and how to?

Answer (score -1):

I think it's simply done via adding `/` at line end.

Comment: Probably a `\\`, actually.